# Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found. Google did not know

Tags: java, android, android-studio, import-libraries

Hello I have a problem with thise error

```
Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.
```

my build.gradle :projeck

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

my build.gradle :app

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.atry.paradox.listdrop"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':library2')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

my settings.gradle

```
include ':app', ':library2'
```

I looking for thise error on google, but I found advice for copy library2 to main file. I have library 2 on the same file where I have app, build, gradle ...

Please where I Do error?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please give more details of what you are trying to do; stackoverflow isn't for code review. I take it you're trying to do something related to an android app, but you need to provide better context.

Comment: I want import library to new project. in mainActivity be nothing. It's only new project and I write on it only compile project(':library2') and :'library2' and copy library2 file into project file.

Comment: i resolved my prolem... but I don't know How.. :)

Answer (score 0):

It depends by the `settings.gradle` file:

```
include ':app', ':library2'
```

Gradle is looking for 2 projects (app and library2).
Each of these projects must have the `build.gradle` file inside.

```
root
|--build.gradle
|--settings.gradle
|--app
|----build.gradle
|--library2
|----build.gradle
```

This error:

```
   Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.
```

happens if a module (or more) doens't have the `build.gradle` file.

Check if your `library2` folder has the `build.gradle` and the right structure.